# How to re-direct logs from Azure Databricks to another destination?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, elastic-beats

We could use some help on how to send Spark Driver and worker logs to a destination outside Azure Databricks, like e.g. Azure Blob storage or Elastic search using Eleastic-beats.

When configuring a new cluster, the only options on get reg log delivery destination is dbfs, see

https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/clusters/log-delivery.html.

Any input much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the following could be helpful :

First you specify a dbfs location for your Spark driver and worker logs.
https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/clusters/log-delivery.html

Then, you create a mount point that links your dbfs folder to a Blob Storage container.
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html#mount-azure-blob-storage-containers-with-dbfs

Hope this help !

Comment: Thank you ! got it working when I had to specify it with `/mnt` in path e.g. `dbfs:/mnt/databricks-cluster-logs`. Specifying just `dbfs:/databricks-cluster-logs` didn't work.

Comment: I have another question. This mount operation needs to be done in the init script ? Or keep the connection alive during a cluster restart ? Or just refreshMount will do the job? Thx