# How to store databricks cluster logs in ADLS

Tags: azure, apache-spark, logging, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a databricks cluster and I want to store my cluster logs in an ADLS Gen 2 account. For that I followed this answer-

[How to re-direct logs from Azure Databricks to another destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962314/how-to-re-direct-logs-from-azure-databricks-to-another-destination)

Also, [this article](https://kapilrajyaguru.medium.com/store-azure-databricks-logs-into-azure-data-lake-gen2-6fd71b5319ce) talks about creating a cluster and sending the logs to ADLS but writes a CURL command to create a cluster.

But this didn't help. I changed the mount script in logging like this-

[image]

But this also didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, Azure Databricks doesn't support writing the logs directly into ADLS (in contrast to AWS & GCP that allow to write directly). The solution would be to mount your storage container into Databrikcs (using [dbutils.fs.mount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts) command) and then point cluster configuration to that mounted location.